# Object initialization of PrepareStatement inside loop can't insert data into database while in case of outside loop it work

Tags: java, insert, prepared-statement

Look this sample code when **pstmt** object is initialized inside for loop this code unable to insert data into database and execute without any exception, error, warning.

But when the **pstmt** *initialization statement* put outside the for loop it will working fine data is inserted into databse.

**Can anyone explain what is the actual reason?**

```
Sample Code:
    
  public static void doSomthing(ArrayList<MyBean>  myBeanList){
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null; 
            String SQLText = "----" ; // SQLText its an insert statement
            //pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQLText);  // putting this line Here working fine
            for (MyBean bean : myBeanList) {
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQLText);  // Problem has solve by putting this line outside the loop
                beanPKey = getNextKey("BK");
                pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(beanPKey));
                pstmt.setString(2, bean.getName());
                pstmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(bean.getDistance()));
                pstmt.setString(4, bean.getDescription());         
                boolean row = pstmt.execute();            
                pstmt.close();
           
            }
        }
```

Comment: What error is generated when you run this code? Does it insert at least the first time (for the first iteration)?

Comment: No.  there is no any error or exception while running this code. It doesn't insert any records event a single record. That's why I put it here. May be some have knowledge about such issue